# What comma rule applies here?

Tags: grammar

"The other cats ran to the kitchen, rushing to their food bowls as quickly as possible. "

So this may be a simple question, but I can't find the exact comma rule for this sentence. Can someone help out? Thank you!

Comment: The only 'rule'  is that the comma marks a natural pause in the sentence.

Comment: With something like "The cats ran to the kitchen shrieking loudly." there is no need for a  comma, but with a longer sentence it is more natural to pause somewhere.